# matching two columns in mysql table in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i am trying to display data using 2 tables in codeigniter, i have a products table with some products and another table with the id of the products, i did the following in controller:

```html
public function index(){
$selectfeatured = $this->product->selectfeatured();
foreach($selectfeatured as $val){
  $id=$val->pid;

$data['featured'] = $this->product->featured($id);
}
        $this->load->view('home', $data);

  }
```

in my model,

```html
function selectfeatured()
          {


            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('featured');
             $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
            $this->db->limit(4);
           $query = $this->db->get();
           $result = $query->result();
           return $result;
          }
      function featured($pid)
        {


          $this->db->select('*');
         $this->db->where("id", $pid);
          $this->db->from('product');

         $query = $this->db->get();
         $result = $query->result();
         return $result;
        }
```

this code only displays one product even though i have multiple products in both the tables, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `$data['feature']` as an array:

```
public function index()
{
    $selectfeatured = $this->product->selectfeatured();
    $data['featured'] = array();
    foreach ($selectfeatured as $val) {
        $id = $val->pid;
        $data['featured'][] = $this->product->featured($id); // add new item
    }
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

And make sure you display the `featured` array right way in your view, something like this:

```
<?php foreach ($featured as $feature) : ?>
    <?php foreach ($feature as $product) : ?>
        <div class="item"><img style="height:250px" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/uploads/products/<?php echo $product->pimage; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: in view am getting error now, trying to get property of non object

Comment: Please upload your view

Comment: its like this <div class="item" ><img style="height:250px" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/uploads/products/<?php echo $product->pimage; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive"></div>
                                </div>

Comment: it starts like this foreach ($featured as $product) {

Comment: Because `result()` in your query return an array. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The variable $data['featured'] is inside a loop and is getting new value on each iteration, and is overwritten on each iteration, that's why you are getting only one product, you need to use array_push or '+=' etc to append the other products.

Comment: can you please show me how

Comment: initialize before the foreach loop
$data['featured'] = array();

loop body:
array_push($data['featured'] , $this->product->featured($id));

Comment: i tried what you said am not getting the display, can u edit my code and show please